# Add and remove class onClick action

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <button class="fbutton btn pull-right filterevents " id="one" >School Events</button>
  <button class="fbutton btn pull-right filterevents" id="two" >Zone Events</button>
  <button class="fbutton btn pull-right filterevents" id="three" >My Events</button>
```

I need to  add class "selected" to specific button onClick.

my code is

```
$("#one").click(function(e) {
                $(this).addClass("fcurrent");
                $("#two").removeClass("fcurrent");
                 $("#three").removeClass("fcurrent");
   });
```

if i use instead of id to class like following ,

```
$(".fbutton").click(function(e) {
                    $(this).addClass("fcurrent");
       });
```

then how to remove the fcurrent class to another two buttons

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(".fbutton").click(function (e) {
$(this).addClass("fcurrent").siblings().removeClass("fcurrent");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/91/)

Comment: @bala Gald to help you :-)

Comment: @bala now i was busy i will ping u later `:-)`

Comment: I hope javascript had this

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".fbutton").click(function(e) {
    $(".fbutton").removeClass("fcurrent");
    $(this).addClass("fcurrent");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove `.fcurrent` class from all button elements , then add your class to current button like this:

```
$(".fbutton").click(function(e) {
    $(".fbutton").removeClass("fcurrent");
    $(this).addClass("fcurrent");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the `fcurrent` class for these buttons, you could remove the class from any other button that has it before adding it to the current button:

```
$('.fbutton').click(function(e) {
    $('.fcurrent').removeClass('fcurrent');
    $(this).addClass('fcurrent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove the class fcurrent from all buttons and then add it again to the one you clicked.

```
$(".fbutton").click(function(e) {
   $(".fbutton").removeClass("fcurrent");
   $(this).addClass("fcurrent");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$(".fbutton").click(function(e) {
    $(".fbutton").removeClass("fcurrent");
    $(this).addClass("fcurrent");
});
```